# Why am I getting the nonsensical "0x8024402C" error when trying to install the .NET Framework 3.5 OFFLINE installer?

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

I have a computer next to me. It's not connected to any network. I have just spent the whole night fighting BIOS settings to be able to install Windows 10 on it.

I'm going to use it for one single task (digitizing VHS tapes), which means I have zero need for it to ever connect to anything.

When trying to install the Elgato Video Capture software, it complains about .NET Framework 3.5 not being installed. And they link to the Microsoft webpage where it's available. Of course, that page defaults to the minimal "online" installer, which is just an EXE which downloads the actual data over the network. So, on the same page, I hunted down the fine-print "offline installer" link, which is of course much bigger, and transferred over it (via an USB stick) to the offline computer.

But I get the same damn generic "0x8024402C" error *even with the offline/full installer*! It acts as if it's trying to "download" data, even though it's all supposed to be in the 200+ MB EXE file. That's the whole point of it being a "full"/offline installer.

Yes, I have restarted the machine, as it suggests itself. That did nothing whatsoever. Same error.

Online, there's of course tons of articles about this, all telling you things related to "fixing your network connection"... But there is no network connection to fix since the machine is *supposed* to be offline. That's why I got the *offline* installer.

What can I possibly do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Framework 3.5 installation packages are included in Windows 10 installation media and can be installed through an administrator command prompt:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /source:X:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

Where `X:` is your Windows 10 DVD / USB drive.

Comment: Thank you. This worked.

Comment: That error message has been retired for 15 years, it's from Microsoft Agent discontinued in 2006.  You must have downloaded a .NET install version expecting an earlier version of Windows.

Comment: @user1292580 Status code 0x8024402C is definitely not discontinued. This is a valid (and up-to-date as of 2023) error code used with Microsoft Update. Microsoft's "Troubleshoot software update scan failures in Configuration Manager" page describes the error: "0x8024402C - The proxy server or target server name cannot be resolved" aka DNS lookup failure. In this specific case, the .NET offline installer was likely missing a prerequisite that it will automatically download from MS Update if not installed. The DISM install will automatically install prerequisites from the Windows image source.